# Oracle 19c/Toad - Need to display NULL and non-NULL values in the result set based on below requirement

Tags: oracle, toad, oracle19c

I am writing a query to pull data from various tables and am new to data analysis.

Here is the problem:

The address (addr1 and addr2 columns) from table B should be displayed as 'NULL' when the addr_cd is not 'R' in table A.
The address (addr1 and addr2 columns) from table B should display values when the addr_cd is having both 'R' and non'R' values in table 'A'.

Currently I have written the below code:

```
with t1 as 
(
select * from table1 a where a.cd = 'R' and exists
    (select b.cd from table1 b where a.id = b.id and b.cd != 'R')
),
t2 as
(
select * from table1 a where a.cd != 'R' and not exists
    (select b.cd from table1 b where a.id = b.id and b.cd = 'EX')
),
t as 
(
SELECT DISTINCT some column names..,
c.addr1,
c.addr2,
left JOIN t1
        ON c.id = t1.id
        AND c.id2 = t1.id2
        AND A.NBR = t1.NBR 
left JOIN t2    
        ON A.id = t2.id
        AND A.id2 = t2.id2
        AND A.NBR = t2.NBR
) select distinct some columns.., id, addr1, addr2 from t;
```

Note- I am currently getting duplicate values (one row with NULL for non'R' cd and one row with values for 'R' cd).
But expected output is to have only rows with values if cd is both 'R' and non'R' for a particular ID.
If ID does not have 'R' value then we need to have rows with 'NULL' values.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I understood it (with my own sample data, as you didn't provide any):

```
SQL> with
  2  b (id, addr1, addr2) as
  3    (select 1, 'Address 1-1', 'Address 1-2' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'Address 2-1', 'Address 2-2' from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'Address 3-1', 'Address 3-2' from dual
  6    ),
  7  a (id, addr_cd) as
  8    (select 1, 'X' from dual union all   --> ID = 1 doesn't have R
  9     select 2, 'R' from dual union all   --> ID = 2 has one R and one non-R
 10     select 2, 'Y' from dual
 11    ),
```

Query begins here: calculate number of `R`s and `non-R`s:

```
 12  temp as
 13    (select id,
 14       sum(case when addr_cd <> 'R' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_not_r,
 15       sum(case when addr_cd =  'R' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_r
 16     from a
 17     group by id
 18    )
```

Finally, join `temp` with `b` on `id` and - according to result of `case` expression - return `NULL` or address values:

```
 19  select b.id,
 20    --
 21    case when t.cnt_not_r * t.cnt_r > 0 then b.addr1
 22         when t.cnt_not_r > 0 then NULL
 23    end as addr1,
 24    --
 25    case when t.cnt_not_r * t.cnt_r > 0 then b.addr2
 26         when t.cnt_not_r > 0 then NULL
 27    end as addr2
 28  from temp t join b on b.id = t.id
 29  order by b.id;

          ID ADDR1       ADDR2
------------ ----------- -----------
           1
           2 Address 2-1 Address 2-2

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the above solution, it worked great for the most part, except that I still seem to be getting duplicates for the scenario where an id has both 'R' and non-R tyoe

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, without "real" sample data, I wouldn't know what should be *improved*. I hope you'll manage to fix it!